# Check if a list item integer is a number between every two item integers in another list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists both containing numbers, and I want to check if the numbers from one list are numbers between every two numbers from the other list? The "other" list has ordered numbers so that every two numbers is an interval like 234, 238, 567, 569, 2134, 2156.

```
ListA = [200, 765, 924, 456, 231]

ListB = [213, 220, 345, 789, 12, 45]
```

I want to check if ListA[0:] is a number between either ListB[0:1] or [2:3] etc.

I have tried this:

```
for i in range(0,len(ListB), 2):
    for x in ListA:
        if i < x < (i:i+2):
            print 'within range'
```

But I get a syntax error for the "i:i+2" :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get what you want.  What do you mean "I want to check if ListA[0:] is a number between either ListB[0:1] or [2:3]"?  ListA[0:] is another list, not a number.

Comment: What did you mean by `x < (i:i+2)`? If you can state it in English, someone can help you translate it to Python.

Comment: We have so many different answers I think a clarification is needed :)

Comment: As a side note, you normally want to name Python variables in lowercase, like `list_a` and `list_b` instead of `ListA` and `ListB`. (You may have noticed that StackOverflow highlighted your variable names as if they were types instead of variables. That's why that happened.)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by ListA[0:] is each item from ListA, and ListB[0:1], [2:3] every two items from ListB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want, although it's not that clear:

```
for i in range(0, len(ListB), 2):
    for x in ListA:
        if ListB[i] < x < ListB[i+1]:
            print 'within range'
```

You're right in your intuition that you can `i:i+2` sort of represents a "range", but not quite like that. That syntax can only be used when slicing a `list`: `ListB[i:i+2]` returns a smaller list with just 2 elements, `[ListB[i], ListB[i+1]]`, just as you expect, but `i:i+2` on its own is illegal. (If you really want to, you can write `slice(i, i+2)` to mean what you're aiming at, but it's not all that useful here.)

Also, from your description, you want to compare `x` to the values `ListB[i]` and `ListB[i+1]`, not just `i` and `i+1` as in your code.

If you wanted to use the slice to generate a range, you could do so, but only indirectly, and it would actually be clumsier and worse in most ways:

```
for i in range(0, len(ListB), 2):
    brange = range(*ListB[i:i+2])
    for x in ListA:
        if x in brange:
            print 'within range'
```

But this is checking for a half-open range rather than an open range, and it requires creating the list representing the range, and walking over the whole thing, and it will only work for integers. So, it's probably not what you want. Better to just explicitly use `ListB[i] < x < ListB[i+1]`.

You might want to consider whether there's a more readable way to build a list of pairs of elements from `ListB`. Without yet knowing about `itertools` and list comprehensions or generator expressions (I assume), you'd probably have to write something pretty verbose and explicit, but it might be useful practice anyway.

Comment: You said, "You might want to consider whether there's a more readable way to build a list of pairs of elements from ListB." [See the zip() function.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: @Catcall: I'm trying to get the OP to figure out a way to write this himself, not hand him code that he doesn't understand.

Comment: btw, [`an_int in range` is a O(1) operation in Python 3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b6ced7bd7d96/Objects/rangeobject.c#l360) though for `step == 1` case the explicit comparison might be better

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, and I actually do encourage people who are clearly learning Python 3 to use `in` with `range`s for that purpose. But people who are clearly learning Python 2 (as you can tell from his `print` statement), it will just confuse them, or at best tantalize them with hints of how things would be better if they put things off until their teacher/web course/whatever decided to teach Python 3…

Comment: This will probably also work! I'm going to try it, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 4):

If what you want to do is *make sure* that all items in list A are within *at least one of* the intervals in list B:

```
>>> listA = [200, 765, 924, 456, 231]
>>> listB = [213, 220, 345, 789, 12, 45]

>>> intervals = zip(*[listB[i::2] for i in range(2)])

>>> [any(low < x < high for low, high in intervals)
                    for x in listA]
[False, True, False, True, False]
```

Comment: Variations on the theme: `intervals = [listB[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0,len(listB),2)]` or `intervals = zip(*[iter(listB)]*2)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Nice! That last one is awesome! Really clever usage of the common `[obj] * n` single-reference pitfall.

Comment: @voithos: It is a standard Python idiom to iterate over an iterable n items at a time. See [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks). "clever" is pejorative term when applied to code: *"Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." – Brian W. Kernighan*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Hmm, I really wish I knew about said idiom a lot earlier - I've hacked my way around that problem more than once without knowing of such an elegant method (in my opinion). And perhaps I should rephrase: I feel like it's a interesting usage of how the `*` operator functions in this case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: +1, because `zip`ping over `*[iter(iterable)]*n` is a standard Python idiom that people should learn how to read and understand. But it's usually better to wrap it up in a function whose name explains what you're doing—especially since you can just copy and paste that function from the recipes in the `itertools` docs, or `pip install more-itertools`. When people see `grouper(2, listB)` it's more immediately obvious what it means.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,len(ListB)-1, 2): #offest 1 less than the length
    for x in ListA:
        if ListB[i] < x < ListB[i+1]: #check if it is between ListB's elements
            print 'within range'
```

at least assuming I understand what you want ...

Comment: You don't need the `len(ListB)-1`. Look at what `range(0, 6, 2)` returns—it's guaranteed to be the same as `range(0, 5, 2)`. (Of course if `ListB` had an odd length that might not be true, but that seems like an invalid input for the OP, so it _should_ raise an error.)

Comment: maybe ... I figured that was beyond the scope of the question ... and I figured he would always want a valid index ...

Comment: Will check this as well, if the other solutions would not work, but they probably will, thanks everyone!